# SQL group by portion of the string

Tags: sql, oracle

My table has entries like

```
01-JAN-92 12.00.00.000000000 AM -04:00
01-JAN-86 12.00.00.000000000 AM -04:00
03-JAN-01 12.00.00.000000000 AM +00:00
03-JAN-01 12.00.00.000000000 AM -04:00
```

And I want to be able to count all the entries that I have for a specific day, instead of taking into consideration the time as well (the last two entries).

So far this is what I  have

```
SELECT ACTIONDATE, count(ACTIONDATE) AS count FROM mytable GROUP BY ACTIONDATE
```

How do I make it so that it groups it by just the day instead of the whole entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TRUNC` to get rid of the time portion:

```
SELECT TRUNC(ACTIONDATE, 'DD'), count(1) AS count
  FROM mytable
GROUP BY TRUNC(ACTIONDATE, 'DD');
```

`TRUNC` truncates the part of the date up to the specified part of it, in this case, the day.

For example, using TRUNC with 'DD' on `SYSDATE` returns:

```
SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'DD') FROM dual;
```

```
TRUNC(SYSDATE,'DD')
-------------------
13/11/21 00:00
```

[TRUNC function in documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm)

Comment: Yup, thanks! This solution worked. Will accept as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Use date() function:

```
SELECT DATE(ACTIONDATE),
  COUNT(ACTIONDATE) AS count
FROM mytable
GROUP BY DATE(ACTIONDATE)
```

EDIT: Sorry. This is in fact mysql format. For the Oracle format, the chosen answer is the more appropriate.

Comment: That's MySQL. Author has set the `oracle` tag.

Comment: I get "missing expression" :( I'm using oracle btw, would this work on oracle?

Answer (score 2):

```
You can easily use the SUBSTRING function :
SELECT SUBSTRING(ACTIONDATE, 1, 9) as ACTION_Day,COUNT(SUBSTRING(ACTIONDATE, 1, 9)) AS        count FROM table1  GROUP BY SUBSTRING(ACTIONDATE, 1, 9)

output:
01-JAN-86 1
01-JAN-92 1
03-JAN-01 2
```